# MongoDB: How to find _id $in array of objects?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a "group" collection which groups documents from another "item" collection. The `group` collection is simply an array of ObjectId's from the `item` collection, however I want to make the objects in the `group` array more complex and still be able to use the `$in` and `$nin` operators.

How can I use `$in` when changing the value used with the `$in` operator to an object instead of only an ObjectId?

```
// current group document
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  items: [
    ObjectId(...),
    ObjectId(...)
  ]
}
// current item find query
db.item.find({ _id : { $in: group.items } }
```

I would like to change the `group` document to look like the following

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  items: [
     { _id : ObjectId(...), name: '...' },
     { _id : ObjectId(...), name: '...' }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform your group array to a simple array of ids to use for your find():

```
// revised item find logic
var itemGroupItemIds = group.items.map(function(item){
    return item._id
});
db.item.find({ _id : { $in: itemGroupItemIds } });
```